# Problems Connecting to SQL Server external list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sql-server, external-content-type

I'm a newbie. I was exploring how to view/edit SQL Server database tables in Sharepoint. After some research I did a two-step process

1. Create an external content type (using Sharepoint Designer) to the SQL Server table
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557243(v=office.14).aspx
2. Create an external list using the external content type just created
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558778(v=office.14).aspx

After I did this our admin was able to see and edit the list but I had permission issues on my account even though I thought I have full rights --

a. I get a message like "Cannot connect to the LobSystem (External System)
b. some similar message
c. or the screen will just churn when I click on the external list and nothing happens

Question: Is this the way to do it or is there another way?

Question: What minimum permissions need to be set up in both Sharepoint and SQL Server to enable viewing/editing for general users? I was haphazardly granting all sorts of permissions just to make it work but no luck.

**[Update:]**

More light on the problem—the sharepoint site is on a virtual machine and the SQL Server is on a network server that hosts SQL. A user logged locally to the virtual machine can see the list whereas a user logging in from a different domain computer in our network experiences the "LOB system" error.

Comment: There are choices to make when you set up the authentication for the ECT to the SQL Server database in SharePoint Designer. Which one did you choose?

Comment: Under connection properties, I got this: authentication mode: user's identity
[x] connection pooling